# django-telegrambot doesn't catch all forwarded messages using WEBHOOK mode

Tags: python, django, webhooks, python-telegram-bot

I use `django-telegrambot` package to make anti-spam telegram bot. The mode for the bot is `WEBHOOK`

I have some functionality to remove all forwarded messages from chat.

My code looks like:

```
if update.message.forward_from or update.message.forward_from_chat:
    bot.delete_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, message_id=update.message.message_id)
    return
```

the code above doesn't work very well, for example when I select a few messages and send them to channel, it deletes only one(sometimes two) messages from forwarded set, sometimes it even doesn't delete if I forward one message, I checked if we always have `forward_from` and `forward_from_chat` when forwarding, yes -- we always have it, also I thought I just have some amount of `pending_update_count`, but it's 0

I know `django-telegrambot` based on `python-telegram-bot` package when I have the same code using only `python-telegram-bot` and run it locally like `python main.py` it works perfect(catch and delete all forwarded messages)

Did someone face with such error here?

Any thinks/suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So ok, after investigating I didn't find where is the trouble here, but when I changed the mode from `WEBHOOK`to `POLLING` -- it works perfectly without any errors